# Retrieve JSON data in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I can't retrieve and print the jobDate data. what's wrong my code?

```
let retrievetime = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "retrieve")as? NSDictionary
print(retrievetime!) 

if let job = retrievetime!["jobs"] as? [String:Any], let jobTitle = job["jobDate"] as? String {
     self.navigationItem.title = jobTitle
     print(jobTitle)
} 

//self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
```

print retrieve time! json output:

```
{
  jobs =({
     jobDate = "2017-08-31";
     jobEndTime = 1504144800;
     jobID = 87;
     jobTime = 1504137600;
  });
  message = "Retrieve Sucessfully";
  result = success;
}
```

Comment: "jobs" is an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use use the `standard` singleton instance and optional bindings to safely get data from `UserDefaults` – unless you registered the key/value pairs.

Second of all **never** use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults` and **never** use `NSDictionary` in Swift unless the compiler tells you to do.

Finally as mentioned in the comments the value for key `jobs` – as the plural form implies – is an array, you have to get the first object of the array

```
if let retrievetime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "retrieve") as? [String:Any] {
   print(retrievetime) 

   if let jobs = retrievetime["jobs"] as? [[String:Any]], 
      let job = jobs.first,
      let jobTitle = job["jobDate"] as? String {
         self.navigationItem.title = jobTitle
         print(jobTitle)
   }
}
```

Comment: And since "jobs" is an array, most likely you should expect 0, 1 or more dictionaries in it and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
let retrievetime = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "retrieve")as? NSDictionary
    print(retrievetime!) 

    if let job = retrievetime!["jobs"] as? [String:Any], let jobTitle = ((retrievetime!["jobs"] as? [String:Any])[0] as? NSDictionary)["jobDate"] as? String {
        self.navigationItem.title = jobTitle
        print(jobTitle)
    } 

//self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
```